# Segmentation fault after compiling in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fault

I wrote the following program in c, but after compiling in Linux using 
gcc -std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST -s -static -lm 
I get a segmentation fault and I can't figure out why.
I searched and found that segmentation faults are mostly about memory issues, but I can't find anything in the code.
Here is the program:

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file_in, *file_out;

    file_in = fopen("file.in.txt", "r");
    fscanf(file_in, "%d", &N);
    fscanf(file_in, "%lf", &a);
    fscanf(file_in, "%lf", &b);
    fscanf(file_in, "%lf", &c);

    fclose(file_in);

    file_out = fopen("file.out.txt","w");
    fprintf(file_out, "%d", M);
    fprintf(file_out, "%s", "\n");

    fprintf(file_out, "%d", a);
    fprintf(file_out, "%s", " ");

    fclose(file_out);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `file` near the end must be `file_out` I suppose

Comment: Can you please post "file.in.txt" too?

Comment: `qsort1(apod1,af, 0, M);` but you have not used element `apod1[0]`

Comment: Make sure `file.out.txt` exists and it's readable by the user running the program.

Comment: _Segmentation fault after compiling in c_ sure, it is difficult before compiling ^^ (relaxing moment)

Comment: use a debugger to find out where the error occurs...

Comment: use **valgrind** to check your memory accesses

Comment: Input is: 4
45000000 2000 10
150000000 2000 10
45000000 2500 20
90000000 2500 5

Comment: I changed some lines in my code, now arrays start at 0 and and at n-1 but still the same problem

Comment: Please post the input and desired output *in the question*, also say what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Output must be: 3
2 1 4

Comment: ... and please don't keep changing the code: this isn't a dynamic code improvment site.

Comment: the exemple you give do not need to be compiled with the options `std=c99 -O2 -DCONTEST -s -static -lm ` what append if you remove them ? Personally if I compile just with the option `-static` valgrind signals strangely `Use of uninitialised value of size 4 at 0x251C0: strcspn` and nothing without `-static`

Comment: I changed the file extension and it worked. There was an incompability of the files in the program with the files in the system. Anyway, thank you everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I used your input file to test your code, and it produces the correct result.

I believe the likely cause is a null pointer deference of `file_in`
You need to check the return value of fopen to make sure it's not NULL

```
 file_in=fopen("file.in.txt", "r");
 fscanf(file_in, "%d", &N);
```

Change the above code to the follow will help.

```
 file_in=fopen("file.in.txt", "r");
 if (file_in == NULL) {
    perror("failed to open file.in.txt"); 
    return 1;
 }
 fscanf(file_in, "%d", &N);
```

Comment: I changed the file extension and it worked. There was an incompability of the files in the program with the files in the system.

Answer (score 0):

A point where you can start from is by reviewing the line:

```
qsort(p, num_elements, sizeof *p, compar);
```

The third argument of function is supposed to take number of bytes of each element (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). So I think that it should be sizeof(SomeDataType) instead of sizeof (*p). Sizeof (pointer to p) should return 4 (on x32bit architecture) or 8 (on x64 architecture) while the actual size of each element in array is 12 bytes (double + int).

Also you could check the actual value of M used to call the function qsort1. Is it inside the actual range of your arrays (100000)?

Comment: `*p` dereferences the pointer, so this is equivalent to `sizeof SomeDataType`.. in fact `sizeof *p` is preferred since it's less maintenance. If the type of `p` ever changes to `SomeOtherDataType` for instance, then `sizeof *p` is still valid and can remain unchanged, whereas `sizeof SomeDataType` would need to be changed to `sizeof SomeOtherDataType`. What you say is correct about `sizeof p`.

Comment: Actually, yes, you are completely right.

Comment: Go on, try it. It will print the size of `SomeDataType`. `*p` dereferences to a `SomeDataType` object, and will print the same as `SomeDataType p; printf("%zu\n", sizeof p);` The size may not necessarily be 12 either, the compiler is free to insert padding into structs for data alignment purposes. The size printed may differ between different compiler flags and different machines.

Comment: I changed the file extension and it worked. There was an incompability of the files in the program with the files in the system.